# Azure AD SAML Authentication SP-initiated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

Are there any usable examples for writing .Net code which would allow SP-initiated SSO using Azure AD as the iDP and SAML2 as the protocol?

Everything I found online either doesn't have examples, doesn't explain clearly, or for the most part it's just outdated. For example, the Attributes tab so many guides refer to seems to be completely missing in Azure AD and so I have no idea how we're supposed to transform claims.

Does anyone have a good guide or sample code? Thanks!

Comment: What SAML client side stack are you using?

Comment: Most likely we'll be using OWIN SAML but open to other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the Kentor stack.

I did some posts [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/12/identityserver-aspnet-mvc-application_16.html) (plus links inside) which show what the OWIN interface looks like.

In your case. you would use the Azure AD metadata. You can get the URL for this from the "Endpoints" tab under "Applications" in the "Active Directory" section.